# C++ defining static object inside class

Tags: c++, class, object, scope, static

I have a class A in "a.h":

```
#include "b.h"

class A {
public:
    static B b;
}
```

I want to initialize b in another function

In "main.cpp":

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

int main () {
    ....
    B A::b = B(arg1, arg2);
```

But the syntax checker give me the error: "member A::b cannot be defined in the current scope." What is the correct way of doing this?

Comment: by the way, this is not a good code style. you should use static constructor as less as possible.

Comment: Why is that? @merito

Comment: because C++ does not define the order of constructing static object. You should use it carefully.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may set the value in `main()` but the definition has to be in the global scope:

```
#include "a.h"
#include "b.h"

B A::b; // <<<<<<

int main () {
    ....
    A::b = B(arg1, arg2);
 // ^^^^
```